# Flow charts in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am creating some flow charts in PowerPoint.

As you know, when these charts get complicated, the lines run into each other and create confusion: are they meant to connect, or were they intended to go through?

I believe Visio has a solution to this where connecting lines automatically "jump" other connecting lines, depicted as a curve. Does PowerPoint have something similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. At least not yet. I would suggest adding a dot or something where the lines *are* supposed to connect.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found was to use the "rainbow" shape, set it to zero width so it looks like a line, then connect lines to each end of it.

I had to use non-elbow connectors or else they misbehave and come in from the wrong directions (still haven't figured that one out!)

Sample below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented with [Route diagram pieces of Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Route_diagram_template) which were invented to depict sub-way and train maps.

Sample diagram created in *PowerPoint*:

[image]

The building blocks for the diagram are route icons of 10x10 mm².

Using *PowerPoint's* "snap to grid" feature, these icons can be easily positioned to align properly. I keep the icons in a *PowerPoint* template file. To insert a given icon in my diagram, I simply copy it via mouse ctlr-left-click-drag&drop.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar, but a bit more simple. I create two rectangles to mask a certain part of the overlapping lines. Once you have "calibrated" the correct size and distance between the rectangles, you can copy-paste and turn them around.

*Sorry, not enough reputation to show an example.*